# MVC4 model validation then submit JSON post to external URI using JQuery

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012

I need to submit a simple form and validate the model. If the model is valid, I would like to serialize that model and send it via POST to an external (https) web service using custom headers. Finally I would handle the response that I get back from the request and display the appropriate message.

I am validating the model from the controller perfectly and serialize the object but can't seem to find a way to create a JSON post request to the external URI. Is there a way to do this using JQuery.ajax or $.post. Maybe I am missing a key ajax param to achieve this.

Thanks

Comment: If you have already passed it to a controller and the model got validated and serialized, can you then make that external call from the controller? Why are you asking for an ajax way, it means you are returning the result from your controller first and then do the external call?

Comment: @von v. I need to know how to create the request with custom headers from the controller once the model has been validated. The response should be handled and the appropriate message (fail/success) displayed on the form.

Comment: If you do an ajax post to your controller, validate the object, serialize it and return it back. So you can use it then for your ajax post to an external URL, does that meet your requirement? If yes, then you are also asking how to include custom header before you do the external post?

Comment: That sounds like exactly what I need to accomplish. I need to add the custom request headers from the controller and then post to external URL using the JSON object as the requestBody. Once the request is processed and a response is returned a message is displayed at the top of the original form.

Comment: If that is **"exactly"** what you need then you won't do it in the controller. Please read my previous comment again. But I'll try and answer your question now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So based on the clarification on the question this is what you can do:

Define the controller method that will validate the object

```
public ActionResult TestMethod() {
    // do server-side validation
    return Json(aValidObject);
}
```

You do an ajax post to your controller so you can validate your model then get back a json result.

```
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("TestMethod")',
    data: some_data,
    type: "post",        
    success: function (result) {
        // result is a valid json object
        doExternalPost(result);
    }
});
```

Add custom header and do the external post

```
function doExternalPost(o) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://some_external_url',
        data: o,        
        dataType: 'json',
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader('custom_header', 'some_value');
        },
        success: function() {
            // post is sucessful 
        },
        error: function (xhr, errorType, exception) {
            var errorMessage = exception || xhr.statusText || xhr.responseText;
            alert('An error has occured: ' + errorMessage);
        },
    });
}
```

Comment: This is "exactly" what I needed. I was trying to make the request from the application which is much harder than it had to be. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
var data = {jsonDataObjectHere};

var request = $.ajax({
    url : 'externalUrl.com/something.whatever',
    type : 'POST',
    data : data // see above
});

request.success(function(response){
    // the response is the stuff from the server
});
```

i'm sleepy so forgive typos

good luck

EDIT: for a bit of clarification, with MVC you really dont need to serialize the json object, mvc will accept it as it is.